# Eclipse Java --> Class

Tags: java, eclipse, class

I made a minecraft mod with eclipse and I have my .java file. I'm not too sure on how to make it a class file that everyone can use, can someone help me please? Thanks.

Comment: If all you want is a class file you might be better of using the command line to compile it.

Comment: You can find a answer in this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279451/how-to-compile-a-class-file-in-java

Comment: It's already been made! Search the bin directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the code written simply just add this to your current code.

```
  package yourpackage.name;

    public class example {
    //Insert your code all within these brackets.
    }
```

If your looking to creating a new class,  right click the src folder, and select new package. Name it something like mine.craft.mod
Then right click your newly created package and select new class. Provide it a name such as example.java and select finish. It should create a newly created class.