# Importing and using a java class in ruby

Tags: java, classpath, jruby

I have a ruby file which contains all the necessary `java_imports` of my ruby project. That file (named `java_import.rb`) is located at `lib/app/wrapper_classes/java_import.rb`.

My java classes are located at `lib/app/gallery/*.java`, in `package gallery;`.

I have tried `include_package "gallery"` and `include_class gallery.ThumbnailFileChooser`, but I feel that I'm missing crucial knowledge.

This is an example of how I include `java librairies` in my `ruby project`.

```
module Awt
    java_import javax.swing.JButton
    java_import javax.swing.JFileChooser
end
```

So the question is : How can I do the same for my classes ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: javax.swing.JButton and javax.swing.JFileChooser are classes. What are you trying to do?

Comment: oh yes, they are classes I successfully imported.
I'm trying to import java classes I've made.
For example, I would like to import lib/app/gallery/ThumbnailFileChooser.java

Comment: You should compile your java classes.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn do you mean something like this here ? [hot to compile a java file in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279451/how-to-compile-a-java-file-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would firstly suggest packaging your classes into a `jar` file in the [typical java fashion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html).  Then you can simply add `require "myjar.jar"` to your JRuby script and work with your classes just as you are doing with the `javax.swing` classes.

If for some reason you cannot do that, [apparently you can include](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/216572#939791) `.class` file directly as follows:

> Let's say I have 'myclass.class' which has a class called 'myclass' in
>   'mypackage.myclass'.  This causes two problems because JRuby doesn't
>   like non-Camelcased classes (because Modules have to have cap-Alpha
>   starts I think).
>
> First, create a directory (under lib/ for example - though not
>   necessary) called mypackage and put myclass.class in there.
>
> Then this should work:
>
> require 'java'
>   $CLASSPATH << 'lib'
>
> myclass = JavaUtilities.get_proxy_class('mypackage.myclass')
>
> @myclass  = myclass.new